Search for a string return multiple results (if found)
As the title suggests, i'm trying to search for a string, and have it return all results matching that string. Here's my code so far:
int search_contact()
{

  if (chdir(getenv("HOME")) == 0)
  {

        FILE *fp;
        fp=fopen(".igterm/hosts4.txt", "r+");
        if ( NULL == fp )
        {
                printf("couldn't open <%s>\n");
                return 1;
        }

        attron(A_BOLD | COLOR_PAIR(2));
        mvaddstr(6,0, "Search      : ");
        attroff(A_BOLD | COLOR_PAIR(2));
        char needle[200];

        scanw("%s",needle);

        char haystack[200];

        int iteration=0;
        char *ptr2needle = NULL;

        while( fgets( haystack, sizeof(haystack),fp) !=NULL)
        {

                header();

                haystack[strlen(haystack)-1] = '\0'; // get rid of the \n

                ptr2needle = strstr(haystack, needle);
                if (ptr2needle)
                {
                        printf("\e[9;01H\e[1;34mSearching for \e[0;37m[\e[1;37m%s\e[0;37m]\e[1;34m... \e[1;34mfound... \e[11;04H\e[0;37m[\e[1;37m%s\e[0;37m]", needle, haystack);
                        break;
                }
        }
        fclose(fp);
        askyesno();
 }
}

I'm trying to search for a string and return all results matching that string. How do I make the code return multiple results?
header() and askyesno() aren't important enough to elaborate on.
EDIT: Still can't get it working.

A function in C can return at most one thing.  You can either return something that encompasses multiple results or change your API to use a callback pattern (or the moral equivalent).

One way to accomplish this would be to have the function return a list of strings.  That might be done by returning a char ** which points to a string which has maybe another string following it.  Or it might be a more complicated structure which contains pointers to strings.  Depends on what is needed.

@wallyk I'm very new to C. How would I accomplish this?

You are mixing global state (getenv()), file I/O, console control and interaction, lack of error handling.  This makes your code hard to test.

Your functions are declared to return int (not strings) and never actually return anything, so they result in undefined behavior.  So it would seem when you say "return all results", you have a different meaning of the word "return" from what is generally understood.  Do you mean "print all the results?"  Or something else?

Yes. Print all results.

@anatolyg
Like this?
        while( fgets( haystack, sizeof(haystack),fp) !=NULL)
        {

                header();
                haystack[strlen(haystack)-1] = '\0'; // get rid of the \n

        do {
                haystack = ptr2needle + 1; // start searching from here
                ptr2needle = strstr(haystack, needle);

        } while (ptr2needle);


                if (ptr2needle)
                {
                        printf("\e[9;01H\e[1;34mSearching for \e[0;37m[\e[1;37m%s\e[0;37m]\e[1;34m... \e[1;34mfound... \e[11;04H\e[0;37m[\e[1;37m%s\e[0;37m]", needle, haystack);
                        break;   
                }   

        }



Code incorrectly assumes haystack must contain a '\n'.  If will not if 1) line is too long 2) fp ends without a '\n'.

ptr2needle = strstr(haystack, needle);
After this code finishes, you have a pointer to your found string. You can now look for it again, starting from a place where it won't be found again. For example:
haystack = ptr2needle + 1; // start searching from here
ptr2needle = strstr(haystack, needle);

This way you can find two occurrences of the needle in the haystack.
To turn this idea into correct code, you should make a loop. It should be a nested loop inside your fgets loop. Repeat the search until the needle is not found anymore.
do {
    ...
    ptr2needle = strstr(...);
    ...
} while (ptr2needle);

